# How to customize QLineEdit like mdb pro inputfield?

Tags: qt, qt5

I would like to make custom QLineEdit to look like MDB Pro InputField

[image][image]

After lineEdit is focused placeholder is animates to QLabel
Can anybody help or guide me through?

Comment: You would need to derive your own class from `QLineEdit` and reimplement the [paintEvent-method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) to draw the widget in different ways depending on its [focus-property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop).

Comment: @SebastianDietrich Thank you for reply! I'm aware of that but dunno what to do ( I've tried to see into Telegram's code but it's difficult to comprehend